# CIL | Content Service | No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: web8.5, cil, content-service, brokerquery

We are trying to query broker database relying on the SDL Web Content Interaction Library (CIL) and Content Broker Query API (C#). 
We keep getting the error - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8081.

The app.config file has the following content:

```
<add key="discovery-service-uri" value="http://example:8082/discovery.svc" />
<add key="oauth‐enabled" value="false" />
```

Session enabled content service runs on the port 8081. All ports are open in windows firewall, OAuth is disabled. Content service is registered as capability in discovery service (http://localhost:8081/content.svc). Services are on Azure Virtual Machine (inbound port rules are also set).

When changing the settings to:

```
<add key="content-service-uri" value="http://example:8081/content.svc" />
<add key="oauth‐enabled" value="false" />
```

Everything works fine. Would appreciate any hints why it would behave so and any suggestions how to enable connection through discovery service. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I guess your CIS services run on a different machine than your web application.

In that case, it is important that your CIS capabilities are *not* registered with `localhost` URLs.  The web app will contact the Discovery Service to retrieve the URL of the Content Service (and other CIS Services). If those are registered with `localhost` URLs, the web app will only be able to connect to them if it is running on the same machine.

Comment: To further add to the answer: go to discovery service directory -> config folder -> get the cd_storage_config -> open and look for the capabilities, make sure that the url for each capability has the host-name of the machine not localhost (if the machine is not localhost) -> update registration of capabilities. You can also do this for individual services if you auto-register on install.